# Merging imported class with namespace in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Valid:

```js
class InputField {
  
}

namespace InputField {
  export enum Types {
    text = "text",
    number = "number"
  }
}

export { InputField };
```

Invalid:

```js
import InputField from "@Controls/InputFields/InputField.vue";
// TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'InputField'

namespace InputField {
  export enum Types {
    text = "text",
    number = "number"
  }
}

export { InputField };
```

How can I merge **imported** `InputField` class with namespace`InputField` (and reexport it)?

### How I'll use the result

```js
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator"
import { InputField } from "@Components/..."


@Component({
  //              Usage as namespace    ↓↓↓
  template: `<InputField type="InputField.Types.number" />`,
  components: {
    InputField // Usage as Vue component
  } 
})
export default class Application extends Vue {
  // Provide access from template
  private InputField: typeof InputField = InputField;
}
```

### Why I need this

```js
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from "vue";
  export default Vue;
}
```

Because of this, TypeScript does not see the public fields of imported classes in `.vue` files

Comment: Hi @GurebuBokofu, you can change the class name of Input field and give a try.

Comment: @sauravsingh thank you for the comment. You mean imported `InputField` class? Would you please to add the answer?

Comment: either change the namespace and or class name which you importing from other path it will work fine.

Comment: @sauravsingh If I change the name of namespace how it will merged when exported? If I change the imported class name, how to re-export it so what it will merge with namespace?

Comment: as i can see you create a namespace just for enum so you can change it.

Comment: @sauravsingh, not only for enum. ...maybe I has not explained how I want to use result? I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can circumvent this `*.vue as VueContructor<Vue>` issue by proxiing it via a `*.ts` file:

```js
import DefaultImportClass, {componentOptions} from "@/source/index.vue"
import {Component} from "vue-property-decorator"

@Component<exportClassName>(componentOptions)
class exportCalssName extends DefaultImportClass {} 
namespace exportClassName {}

export {exportClassName}
```

**BUT**

You can use static to achive the same result as done via namespace:

```js
enum Types {
  Text: "text",
  Number: "number"
}

@Component
export class InputFieldTypes extends Vue {
  static Types = Types
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Please tell me why we need `componentOptions` and `<exportClassName>`.

Comment: Oh, I see, components option is from vue library... So I should to write my components in '.ts' file, should not I?

Comment: The component decorator is generic you have to tell it the type of the component - also it takes component options. If you are able to write those renderfunctions it might be more atomic to drop those into mixins ( *.ts)

Answer (score 0):

### Limitation

```js
@Component({
  template: `<input type="HTML_Type" />`
})
export default class InputField extends Vue {

  //              Vue will not see this !! ↓↓   
  @Prop({ default: InputField.Properties.Types.text, type: String }) 
  private readonly HTML_Type!: string;
}

namespace InputField {
  export enum Types {
    text = "text",
    number = "number"
  }
}
```

It could be solved by static fields.